# Convert org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue to integer in scala

Tags: json, scala

I would like to convert Convert org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue (JString) to integer in scala, is there anybody have a hint?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/json/JsonAST.scala.html
you can do

```
val x: JString = ...
val i: Int = x.values.toInt
```

Note that `toInt` will throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the string can not be converted to an integer.
You can use a `Try` here to "capture the exception and react properly.

Comment: Dear Martin, it is not working for my situation. Anyway I already found another way to implement and solve my issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. let us know your solution! 2. why is it not working? 3. next time try a raise a concise question.

Answer (score 0):

this is all of current working code:

```
                val multiCategoryOne =
                    for { JString(x) <- (content \\ "ancesstorCategories").children} yield x

                 var multiCategoryMany:List[Object] = Nil
                if(multiCategoryOne == Nil){
                    // multiple items in cart
                    val elements = (content \\ "ancesstorCategories").children
                    for ( acct <- elements ) {
                        val eachMultiCat = for { JString(x) <- acct} yield x
                        multiCategoryMany = multiCategoryMany ::: List(eachMultiCat)
                    }

                }else{
                    // one item in cart
                    multiCategoryMany = multiCategoryMany ::: List(multiCategoryOne)
                }
```